# Compute levels of a variable during subsetting using ddply

Tags: r, plyr

I need to calculate the number of categories of a variable for each level of a factor in a huge matrix. I tried using ddply in the following script, but it doesnt work and i cant figure out why.

Here it goes my code with a sample dataframe:

```
a<-as.factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3))
b<-as.factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,3,1,2,3))
df=data.frame(a=a,b=b)

records=ddply(df, .(a),
          summarise,
          categories=length(levels(b))
          )              
records
```

it should give:

```
a categories
1 1          1
2 2          2
3 3          3
```

Anybody has a hint? it got me completely stuck..
thanks!
Agus

Answer (score 0):

The levels of a factor do not change when you subset it. The levels represent the *possible* values that a factor may take on, not the set of values it does. So you can replace your code with

```
records=ddply(df, .(a),
          summarise,
          categories=length(levels(droplevels(b)))
          )
```

or even

```
records=ddply(df, .(a),
          summarise,
          categories=length(unique(b))
          )
```

either of which gives

```
> records
  a categories
1 1          1
2 2          2
3 3          3
```